# CS Cart 4.0.1: how to make order payable only after confirmation?

Tags: php, e-commerce, cs-cart

We're trying to build a shop with CS Cart 4.0.1, and we need to let users pay their orders (via the usual payment processors, eg. PayPal) only after they have been given green light by a shop admin. Example workflow:

1. customer shops around, goes to check out, confirms his order
2. order shows up in status "Received", but CS Cart wouldn't let the customer pay it
3. admin reviews the order and changes order status to a new one, like "Payable"
4. CS Cart lets the user pay
5. when CS Cart's payment processors receives the payment, it automatically switch the order to status "Completed"

I did look around but I cannot seem to find an option to do that nor an add-on implementing this functionality. Anyone knows if it is possible (either "stock" or via addons), or if it absolutely needs a patch to CS Cart code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cs-cart does not allow to do this, and I am afraid that it requires some core modification.

Comment: just to be sure: do you mean that it would not be possible even with add-ons (eg. maybe because CSCart lacks some hooks in the right places) ?

Comment: Yes, it seems, there is no ability to make it through add-on, it will require any changes in the core files. Maybe just a small changes, adding a new hook for example.